# PyDev using Pylint: No output in Problems View, only in Console

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I am using (a clean install off) **Eclipse version 3.7.2** with **PyDev for Eclipse, version 2.4.0.2012020116** (both the latest stable versions at the time of writing). The Eclipse installation is dedicated to be used for Python development so I don´t have a lot of plugins installed.

**I am able to run pylint while redirecting output to the Eclipse Console**, but I can **not** see anything in the **Problems view**.

The URL http://pydev.org/manual_adv_pylint.html mentions that I should enable `...pydev.pylint...` in the *Problems view filter*. Which I can not find. I suspect it has been removed from Eclipse and that the page is obsolete.

I am able to find the `View Menu` in the upper right corner of the `Problems view`. If I look under it at `Configure Contents` I can see that `Show all items` is checked and that `PyLint Problem` exists and is checked under `Types`.

Related facts:

- In `Windows / PyDev` I have set `Location of pylint (lint.py):` to 
  `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pylint-0.25.1-py2.7.egg\pylint\lint.py`.
- I installed `pylint` using `easy_install`.
- Pylint works from the command line, and of course, inside Eclipse when output is directed to the Eclipse Console. But I would much rather have it in the Problems view.
- My Eclipse project structure is simple.

  - I have my PyDev workspace at `C:\Users\extntf\pydevws`.
  - I have a `PyDev project` called `Test` in it.
  - The project

    - uses the `PyDev Builder` and has the (workspace relative path) `/Test`.
    - has `PYTHONPATH` set to `/Test`
    - is of type `Python` and has `Grammar Version` set to `2.7`.
  - Inside it I have a module called `TestModule.py` with the following two lines:`names = ['Monday','Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
    print 'Hello ' + ' and '.join (names) + '!!'`

If I need to provide anything else to be able to get help, please let me know in a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just took your code and things seem to work as expected, so, I guess your problem is that by default, PyDev will ignore 'Conventions' and 'Refactoring' suggestions from PyLint (only Conventions issues where reported in your code).

So, go to window > preferences > pydev > pylint and change the severity for the 'Conventions' and 'Refactorings' if you want those to appear as problem markers.

Comment: Thank you! You are absolutely correct, I missed that distinction in the console output and wondered why the same things did not show in the Problems view.